# How to type a string with newlines on Selenium chrome IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, newline, execute-script

I'm trying to use Selenium IDE to type and submit a handful of strings on a website. Each string is a list of three names that must be separated with each name on its own line. I'm using an execute script command to return the list of strings, but I get a "Failed: invalid or unexpected token" error message if there are any newline characters in the strings.

Here's what it looks like:

| Command | Target | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| execute script | return ["name1**\n**name2**\n**name3", "name4**\n**name5**\n**name6", ...] | stringList |
| for each | stringList | string |
| type | text field | ${string} |
| click | submit button |  |
| end |  |  |

That all works great if I remove the newline characters. I can even replace the newlines with spaces (\s) and it parses that just fine:

```
name1 name2 name3
```

Unfortunately, I need it to look like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

The newline characters also work if I use a text command and put a single string directly into the value field. I don't why Selenium won't allow the newline character in this specific case, but I'm kind of stuck looking for a workaround. Thanks in advance for any help.